# How to import a python module from other folder

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, python-import

let's say in my working project directory I have this tree structure :

```
- project
    - lib
        - monitoring
            - analysis.py
            - database.py
            - monitor.py
            - files.py
        - server.py
        - exec.py
    - template
        - some HTML files
```

file: *analysis.py*

```
from files import *;
from database import db;
```

file: *files.py*

```
#this script doesn't import from any of them
```

file: *monitor.py*

```
from database import db;
from files import Time, isFileExists
```

file: *database.py*

```
from files import *;
```

file: *server.py*

```
from exec import Run;
from monitoring.files import rootFolder , subContent , ROOTPATH , FOLDERNAME , Time , fullDate;
```

file: *exec.py*

```
from monitoring.analysis import Collect;
```

My **problem** occures 
when I run script *exec.py* I got : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'

Comment: please refer to this question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/4383571/11548820

Comment: @uditkanotra Thanks for your reply.
I read this question before. But I think my question is a little bit different.
In my question *exec.py* is in the same level of *monitoring* folder

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:***

ADD **__init__.py** file in the monitoring folder, this is to inform python that monitoring is also a python package from which we can import modules

**Ensure that a file called __init__ is added to the folder that contains the module you want to import. This file is typically empty**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have added this file but still not working. also I think because I run python >= 3.x this file is optionally

Comment: so you added that file in monitoring folder correct?

Comment: Yes I have added a file named __init__.py in *project/lib/monitoring*

Comment: please name it ** __init__.py**.py

Comment: your python version please

Comment: python 3.6.3 
Kubuntu 18.04